# How to change default font of "g" in equations?

Tags: fonts, equations

[image]

I hope to change default font of equations of "g" like 
[image]

Comment: It's the same shape as the text italic g in the Computer Modern fonts.

Comment: But I hope in PDF, the font in equation of "g" could not be "g",

Comment: It makes no sense, sorry. Choose a different font for the whole document.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the best font of "g" in equations?

Comment: You don't look at *one* letter, but at the whole font. For Computer Modern, Knuth decided to have an “open italic g”. Other fonts may do different choices. There is no “better” or “worse”.

Comment: this is the traditional shape of an italic g as used for math (or usually for text, for that matter). that is true in most fonts used for math, including times and lucida.  however, if you really must, you can define a symbol using the cm "slanted" font, accessed with `\slshape` or `\textsl`.  but beware -- used in math, the spacing may not be correct unless you make special adjustments.  this is really not a good idea, so the details will be left unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

The following example defines `\g` to use the glyph from the slanted text font.
If you do not use CM/EC/LM fonts as text fonts, then the macro also should set the correct family to match the math font (e.g. `\newcommand*{\g}{\text{\fontfamily{cmr}\slshape g}}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\newcommand*{\g}{\text{\slshape g}}
\begin{document}
\[ U_{C\g v}(k) = \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]